# web.py how to generate dynamic urls

Tags: python, web

I am trying to use web.py for my framework. My requirement is to generate urls dynamically like below

```
import web
render = web.template.render('templates/')

urls = (
  '/', 'index',
)


class index:
    def GET(self):
        name = "Salil"
        return render.index_1(name)

class system:
    def GET(self):
        return render.index()

def populate_url():
    global urls
    urls = urls + ('/hello', 'system')
    print urls

if __name__ == "__main__":
    populate_url()
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

But this doesn't work. when I access in browser , ( http://ipaddress/hello ) it says 'not found'

What is the best way to achieve what I want to do.

Thanks
~S

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to design more flexible url patterns.

In your case I think

```
urls = (
  '/.*', 'index',
)
```

will help

Comment: This will not help, I want to redirect to different classes based on URLs

Comment: you can dispatch your request to different classes using python code in the index function

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the 'solution' for the current problem. But didn't dig deep into why it behaves so !!

First I declare the tuple without any value in it

urls = ()

then add all values to the tuple.

Then it works.

~S